# ¿Como puedo enviar datos de un formulario hecho con react-hook-form a mi api?

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hook-form

Buen día, he estado probando react-hook-form para hacer varios formularios de mi proyecto pero tengo una dudas al tratar de enviar los datos a un endpoint determinado (Ej: http://localhost:3000/login). Lo único que tengo es un objeto (data) y en la documentación solo muestran esto:

```
const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data);
```

Este es mi formulario de ejemplo:

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

const Login = () => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="container mx-auto justify-center">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <input
            className="bg-blue-100"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Usuario"
            name="user_name"
            ref={register({
              required: true,
              minLength: 6
            })}
          />
          {errors.user_pass && 
            <div>
              <span>Introduzca 6 caracteres como minimo</span>
            </div>
          }

          <input
            type="password"
            placeholder="Contraseña"
            name="user_pass"
            ref={register({
              required: true,
              minLength: 6,
            })}
          />
          {errors.user_pass && 
            <div>
              <span>Introduzca 6 caracteres como minimo</span>
            </div>
          }

          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Pregunta: ¿como puedo mandar los datos de mi formulario al backend?

Comment: Puedes hacerlo mediante [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo utilizar está librería [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

```
const axios = require('axios');
 
// Make a request for a user with a given ID
axios.get('/user?ID=12345')
  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })
  .then(function () {
    // always executed
  });
 
// Optionally the request above could also be done as
axios.get('/user', {
    params: {
      ID: 12345
    }
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
  .then(function () {
    // always executed
  });  
 
// Want to use async/await? Add the `async` keyword to your outer function/method.
async function getUser() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('/user?ID=12345');
    console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```